# Dynamically change type with JMS Serializer and Symfony

Tags: jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I would like to dynamically decide what's the type of the object JMS Serializer is just about to serialize.

For example, I have two properties, one for storing the discount value, and another one for discount type. If discount type is 0, then discount value is just number (meaning "this number of percent you receive as disocunt"). For discount_type = 1, you will have Money object in the discount_value (Money object is amount and currency).

The output should be following:

```
{
 ...
 discounts: [
    {
      value: 10,
      type: 0
    },
    {
      value: {
        money_value: 50,
        money_currency: EUR
      },
      type: 1
    }
 ]
}
```

Is there a way to do that? I need defined type in Entity.Class.yml as I need to do some deserialization later.

Answer (score 0):

For this case you could try using `@Discrimantor` [annotation.](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#discriminator)
So that you could have some abstract discount value class and two descendants of it with different fields and mapping.